# Do we need both Automapper and Automapper.Net4 dlls to use Automapper?

Tags: c#-4.0, automapper

Do we need Automapper and Automapper.Net4 dlls together to use the Automaper functionality in our code.

I mean can't we just have the one dll of them both. Using Automapper for the first time.

Need help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8):

All you need to do is do "Install-Package AutoMapper" and you're set. Because AutoMapper supports all major .NET platforms, things that are specific to *your* platform are in a platform-specific assembly. This is a very common approach for building cross-platform libraries.

In short, you shouldn't care, because NuGet takes care of everything for you. It's completely transparent to you as a user. You don't have to do anything extra to take advantage of the platform-specific features.

Comment: This answer from the library's author should be [**accepted as the answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: What about deployment though? Which ones should be deployed as you don't know what platform it will be running on.

Comment: What do you mean? Who is "you" here?

Comment: i have the same question actually, i've upgraded to version 4.0.4 and no longer have the AutoMapper.Net4 dll. If i now leave this file out of my deployment scripts, will that be ok?

Comment: There are no more platform-specific extension assemblies. I'm actually compiling AutoMapper for each individual platform, each having a unique assembly built just for it. Effectively the .Net4.dll assembly is combined into the one AutoMapper.dll. So you should *delete* that file.

Answer (score 2):

Why not ask Jimmy? [AutoMapper using Portable Class Libraries](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2013/09/04/automapper-3-0-portable-class-libraries-and-platformnotsupportedexception/).

From looking at the NuGet package, it would appear Automapper.dll is the core (it's common to all platform libraries), while Automapper.Net4.dll is the platform specific - both are necessary.

Comment: It is not true, both are NOT necessary. In fact the Automapper.Net4.dll can cause you a lot of problems like us!

Answer (score 1):

This is actually the correct answer:

> Effectively the .Net4.dll assembly is combined into the one AutoMapper.dll. **So you should delete that file.** (Jimmy Bogard)

We spent the whole afternoon with a team debugging what is wrong (I got one customer bug report) and could not reproduce. Then finally we found out that the problem is with  Automapper.Net4.dll. After deleting it, bug went away (before we already located in the code that the problem is with automapper).

Comment: When I disable 'Enable Just My Code' in VS2017, I get a soft error that it first tries to load the Net4.dll. Why is that? If what you say is correct, it wouldn't need to do so?

Comment: Well which version do you have? This VS error might be caused by some other thing you are trying to achieve - for example IDE wants to load it?

Answer (score 0):

Both are combined into just one nuget Package: Automapper