# AutoMapper returns null for all values in simple mapping case

Tags: entity-framework, automapper, identity, dto

I am using Entity Framework 6 with MVC and Web API and I have been toying with whether to use Data Transfer Objects (DTO's) for the JSON api side of things.. 
I came across AutoMapper and having written some DTO's manually thought (still think) this should be a good way to manage the DTO's.
So, New to it, installed via Nuget, I tried my first mapping. The mblUser class derived from IdentityUser as the source, and I want a simple APIUser to go down the wire..heres the classes:

```
    public class mblUser : IdentityUser 
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<mblUser> manager, string authenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie) 
    {
        //authentication type added to provide for Bearer type of authentication. Still defaults to cookie though so as not to impact the code
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, authenticationType );
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
    [Display(Name = "Date of Birth IDVIEW")]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}",
        NullDisplayText = "Please Enter Your Date of Birth", 
        ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]

    public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName {get; set;}
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public virtual Leader Leader { get; set;}
    public virtual Guardian Guardian { get; set; }
    public virtual Participant Participant { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    [Display(Name ="Full Name")]
    public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            return FirstName + (MiddleName !=null ? " " + MiddleName : "") + (LastName != null ? " " + LastName :"");
        }
    }
    [NotMapped]
    [Display(Name ="Details Complete")]
    public bool DetailsComplete
    {
        get
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(FullName.Trim()) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Email) ) 
            {
                // set true if we have something of a name and an email address.. 
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

.. and heres the APIUser:

```
    public class APIUser
{
    private string Id { get; set; }
    private string Email { get; set; }
    private string UserName { get; set; }
    private string Title { get; set; }
    private string FirstName { get; set; }
    private string MiddleName { get; set; }
    private string LastName { get; set; }
    private string DisplayName { get; set; }
    private string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

... and heres the mapping code:

```
        // GET: api/userSettings/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(APIUser))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetmblUser(string username)
    {
        mblUser User = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(username);
        if (User == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        Mapper.CreateMap<mblUser, APIUser>();

        APIUser dto = Mapper.Map<APIUser>(User); <-- here all User members are valid and populated.

        return Ok(dto); <--at a breakpoint here.. all dto members are null.
    }
```

I figure I must be doing some kind of Newbie error or something but cant figure out what? I did wonder if it is because the mblUser is derived from IdentityUser but the documentation is far from clear on that issue.

Out of interest, I did spot another issue that seems related [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28082756/do-we-need-both-automapper-and-automapper-net4-dlls-to-use-automapper) and I do indeed have AutoMapper.Net4 in my references as well as AutoMapper, but I have also seen that it is required elsewhere, so am a bit stuck .. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It looks like something is backwards in your code. Is the name of the source type "mblUser"? Or User?

Comment: Well the `ApiUser` properies are all `private`.  If you make them public, does Automapper map them?

Comment: Doh! Well spotted Amy.. I'm not able to try it till tomorrow now but I bet that's it..! I'll try it and come back. .  If so that's a stupid cut and paste error on my part from my original home brew mapping code. . Many thanks.  Optimistically Brett

Comment: I'll submit it as an answer, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make your properties public before they can be mapped.

```
public class APIUser
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Yup.. that was it.. my apologies to the world out there.. but you know how it is when sometimes it is just staring you in the face.. thanks again Amy. Brett